# TypeError: input expected at most1 arguments got 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Hi could someone please help explain to me what has gone wrong?

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Python Scripts/Stuff I do when bored/Guessing game.py", line >.13, in <module>
>   guess = int(input("Hi",name,"you will need to guess a number between 1-10"))
>TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

And the code

```
import random


guesses_taken = 0

print("Welcome to the number guessing game")
name = input("Hi what is your name?")
random_number = random.randint(1,10)



while guesses_taken < 3:
    guess = int(input("Hi",name,"you will need to guess a number between 1-10"))
    if guess in random_number:
        print("Well done you guessed it correctly!")
        exit()

    elif guess not in random_number:
        guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1
        print("Unlucky! Try again!")

if guesses_taken >= 3:
    print("Unlucky! Guess it's game over now!")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.format` method of strings:

```
"Hi, {}, you will need to guess a number between 1-10".format(name)
```

The issue is that you are supplying values separated by commas to the `input()` function. This tells the function to take these values as separate arguments. Since `input` only takes one argument (the prompt), an error is raised.

Comment: format is probably better practice, tbh. You could also use `%s`

Comment: `%s` is more Python 2 than Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

It should look like

```
guess = int(input("Hi"+name+"you will need to guess a number between 1-10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to concatenate the strings using the `+`

```
guess = int(input("Hi" + name + "you will need to guess a number between 1-10"))
```

since input is a method, when you use commas, it thinks you're putting in three arguments, rather than a single joined string

Answer (score 1):

the error message tells you exactly, what's happening:

> "**input** expected at most 1 arguments, got 3"

there's a function `input()` somewhere in line 13

> "input **expected at most 1 arguments**, got 3"

the typical way to call the function is `input(string_to_show)`, so it's a function of just one variable, see the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

> "input expected at most 1 arguments, **got 3**"

you seem to call the function somehow like this: `input(a, b, c)`, so you pass three variables instead of one. that's an error

as other guys have pointed out, you need to concatenate your words `a`, `b` and `c` into one single string variable in order to pass it to `input()`. User @bern has suggested a nice method of doing so using `format()`.